# Android annotations and flavors in Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations, android-productflavors

i'm trying  to add two flavors in my project, I already have android annotations and it's working fine without the favors, but when I'm adding the two favors the MainActivity_ class is generated only for one of the flavors when changeing the build variant. 
Any ideas on how could you add flavors and still use the annotations?

Android annotations version is '3.2'

My android section in gradle looks like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "$PackageName"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {

        }
        flavor2 {

        }
    }
}
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "$PackageName"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the responsibility of the android-apt plugin. Can you consult its issue tracker or sg?

Comment: Related `android-apt` [issue](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issue/34/android-apt-android-annotations-multiple#comment-None).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm myself using AndroidAnnotations for a while now and I have a few projects that require product flavors as well. So far I managed to make it work.

My guess would be that you misconfigured your *resourcePackageName* in your apt.

Here is what I do in my (truncated) **build.gradle** file:

```
ext {
APP_NAME = "your app name here"
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId APP_GROUP
    versionName APP_VERSION
    versionCode 1

    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

apt {
arguments {
    androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
}
}
```

You might also want to have a custom applicationId for each flavor your using. You can do it that way:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId android.defaultConfig.applicationId + ".flavor1"
    }
    flavor2 {
        applicationId android.defaultConfig.applicationId + ".flavor2"
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your issue ;)