# productFlavors application id with android annotation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, android-productflavors

I'm Trying yo do a multiBuild with android studio, but i'm getting an error when i add applicationId "***"

In my build.gradle i add productFlavors

```
     productFlavors {
    music {

    }

    sport {
        applicationId "com.trueorfalse.ouam.truefalse.sport"
        versionName "1.0-free"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "false"
    }

}
```

i'm getting this error:

```
  Error:(14, 55) error: cannot find symbol class HomeFragment_
  Error:(15, 60) error: cannot find symbol class QuestionFragments_
  Error:(27, 5) error: cannot find symbol class HomeFragment_
  Error:(14, 55) error: cannot find symbol class HomeFragment_
  Error:(15, 60) error: cannot find symbol class QuestionFragments_
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileSportDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Is like Android annotation doesn't work  why ?

if i delete applicationId all work

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here: [Android annotations and flavors in Android Studio 1.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362494/android-annotations-and-flavors-in-android-studio-1-0-1)

I add 
          apt {
           arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
           }

I modify productFlavors like this:

```
   productFlavors {
        music {
            applicationId android.defaultConfig.applicationId + ".music"
        }
        develop {

        }

        sport {
            applicationId android.defaultConfig.applicationId + ".sport"
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not config **Android Annotation** in right way. 
pay attention to the annotation in **apt->arguments**:

> you should set your package name here if you are using different
>   application IDs

```
defaultConfig {
            applicationId "your.package.name"
            ...
}

//Config Android annotations
apt {
        arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
            // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

            // you should set your package name here if you are using different application IDs
            // resourcePackageName "your.package.name"
            resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId

            // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
            // logLevel 'INFO'
            // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}

    productFlavors{
                mj360 {
                    applicationId android.defaultConfig.applicationId + ".mj360"
                    resValue "string", "app_name", "MyDemo"
                }
                ...
}
```